# No HDMI audio out, and low volume on speakers

Tags: 16.04, sound, hp

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my HP pavilion dv6-3134ca. I've also installed PulseAudio volume control after having some audio issues and it didn't help.

All my sound settings are at max, but I can barely hear the laptop speakers. They worked fine before installing Ubuntu. More importantly, I cannot play audio out through my HDMI. The HDMI video works fine but no audio at all. There is no option for HDMI out or for S/PDIF out in either sound settings or PulseAudio control! I can only see output settings for Speakers and Headphones.

I only use this laptop to watch movies on my TV so without HDMI audio out it's essentially useless.

Answer (score 0):

first let me see the output of `aplay -l`
if it has `HDMI` in it then:

`speaker-test -c 2 -D hw:0,3`

> This requires that you are connected via HDMI to other device

press `Ctrl+C` after you here both the speakers

then you problem would be solved by installing `pavucontrol`

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Goto the `configuration` tab and select the suitable setting

and to solve the laptop problem install

`sudo apt-get install alsamixergui`

type in terminal `alsamixergui` and set the master volume to full

Comment: aplay -l shows this message:

Comment: the output of 'aplay -l' is the following
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: 92HD81B1X5 Analog [92HD81B1X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: this should have had HDMI in it... Try it with HDMI connected and try the `pavucontrol` and let me know

Comment: hdmi was connected and no hdmi output showed up in pavucontrol. the hdmi video did display on my tv, just no audio. i would also note that my laptop has an intel/amd switchable graphics card if that makes a difference.

Comment: it doesnt give me the option to select hdmi audio out. only headphones or speakers, this is while hdmi is attached and video is showing on the tv. i have a switchable graphics card (AMD). i have found ways to install the AMD driver but only if i install a previous version of ubuntu.